# Событие из ListBox Scroll C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как создать событие когда вертикальный Scroll в ListBox доходит до конца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Решение

Допустим, что используется `ListView` с некоторым списком. Добавляешь ему следующий обработчик:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ListView_ScrollChanged">
   <!--Something_here-->
</ListView>
```

В коде обработчика пишешь это:

```
private void ListView_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.ExtentHeight - e.ViewportHeight - e.VerticalOffset == 0)
   {
      // Enter your code here...
   }
}
```

## Пример

`XAML:`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Title="Scroll to bottom" Height="400" Width="450">
    <ListView VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
              ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ListView_ScrollChanged">
        <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" Height="100" Width="400"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightCoral" Height="100" Width="400"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" Height="100" Width="400"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightCoral" Height="100" Width="400"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" Height="100" Width="400"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightCoral" Height="100" Width="400"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" Height="100" Width="400"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightCoral" Height="100" Width="400"/>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

`C# Code-behind`

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ListView_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ExtentHeight - e.ViewportHeight - e.VerticalOffset == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Is bottom!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает.

Comment: @ЮраТатарников ответ в таком случае можно отметить как принятый. Галочка расположена слева от ответа.